# How to fill images in to UICollectionView with Alamofire Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, uicollectionviewcell, alamofireimage

I have a Chat Log which is simply a `UICollectionView`. Every sell has an avatar (`UIImage`) and a text bubble. I'm trying to **fill avatars** with proper images by fetching avatars URL from the server with **Alamofire** like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "chatMessage", for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell

    let imageURL = URL(string: messagesArray![indexPath.item].userAvatar)
            Alamofire.download(imageURL!).responseData { response in
                if let data = response.result.value {
                    cell.userAvatar.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }

    cell.messageText.text = messagesArray![indexPath.item].userText
}
```

**My problem:** In some cells avatar appears in some is not. I think it's related to Alamofire async work. So my question is how to fill images to `UICollectionView` properly to show each avatar in each cell?

Comment: you think? did you do any debugging? did you confirm that all the calls succeed, that you are getting back the data and that images are created for them?

Comment: You should consider creating an view with an activity indicator.  Just before making your network call, bring this view up and activate the activity indicator.  This is standard practice.  When the network call completes, stop the indicator, close the view, and reload the data at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to use SDWebImage , as according to your current implementation image fetching happens multiple times

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

here [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView reuses existing cells. If you have a collectionView with one million cells there are not going to be one million UICollectionView cells instantiated but they got reused when they scroll out. Now your result callback blocks may set the image of the same cells.

To solve your problem you need to cache the images. There are multiple tutorials about this topic.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You just one step further than my question is. I solved the current issue with @Sh_Khan answer. But know I see my cells started to render differently as I'm scrolling.